# How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically adding keyboard layouts (i.e. US keyboard)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, language, input-languages

**Update:** this is a lengthy post, you can [jump straight to the answer below](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-remove-us-keyboard-from-windows-10-language-list#1094953)

---

**Note:** The quick language list refers to the list in the screenshot below, accessible throught the shortcut *Win + Space bar*

I have two languages for windows spell check in my system, **English (United States)** and **French (Switzerland)**, but despite both languages being properly configured with "Swiss French" input keyboard, **US Keyboard** input keeps appearing on this list:

[image]

Here's the settings for **English (United States)** language, you can see the only input is "Swiss French":

[image]

Same for **Français (Suisse)**, the only input is "Swiss French":

[image]

In the Control Panel, both are also set as Swiss French:

[image]

All my settings are set to use "language list":

[image]
[image]

Here's a few things that I already tried:

- I already managed to remove it by some language configuration gymnastics, by adding and removing languages, it always eventually comes back
- I have already done this: https://superuser.com/a/484595/168632
- There's no mention of US Keyboard in my registry settings either:

[image]

Please help, I'm desperate, this is my third computer with Windows 10 and they all do the same thing.

Comment: what if you need some script which would run at Autostart+DELETE THOSE UNWANTED ENTRIES?

Comment: Win + Shift + Space bar

Comment: [Windows 10 April 2018 Update added an extra Language and I cannot remove it](https://superuser.com/a/1321743)

Comment: Only this worked for me https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/cant-remove-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10/058acf33-16d9-47f4-a24b-245b8823d90e  And this also blocks from adding new layouts unless you allow it

Answer (score 186, accepted):

To fix this issue, delete the **Preload** registry folder and sign out **or** restart the computer:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload
```

This folder seems to be some legacy remnant that contains non-user-specified keyboard layouts to be added to the list of languages when the user signs in. **While the fix itself works through restarts, at time of writing there's things that bring back that pesky folder**, here's a few that I bumped into personally:

- Remote desktop to a computer with US layout
- Using the same Microsoft account on another PC that still has this
  issue

Whenever the problem comes back, that registry folder needs to be deleted again.

**Edit 2:**
Thanks to @Lu55's suggestion, here's a handy one-liner to use on a command prompt with admin privileges:

```
reg delete "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload" /f
```

**Edit:**
I have created a `RemovePreload.reg` text file with the following content, this way this fix can easily be re-applied every time without navigating the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload]
```

To use this, save it in a text file and change the extension from `.txt` to `.reg`. Then whenever it comes back, you can just double click it and restart or sign out.

Comment: Thanks! This was the only thing that finally fixed it for me. The US keyboard layout always got added when I logged in. I could remove it by first adding it, and then removing it, like Snaiper's answer, but it would always reappear when restarting. This seems to have removed it permanently.

Comment: It appears after a while anyway.

Comment: Yea, it reappeared for me now too :( Was able to restart only once without it reappearing it seems.

Comment: The solution of adding and removing the keyboard is way safer and as hacky as this one :)

Comment: Have you tried, instead of removing the `Preload` key, to remove its entries and restrict permissions to the key? I went to permissions of `Preload`, Advanced, disabled inheritance, converted all inherited permissions, removed all of them, added read-only permission for `Everyone`, and saved. That should prevent Windows from re-adding the entries that re-add keyboard profiles.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me as of 2020-04-10, while the less hacky solution of adding/removing keyboard doesn't work after rebooting. I really hope that Microsoft actually sorts this stupidity out, eventually.

Comment: This worked for me on 14Apr2020, with Win10EducationN 1909 - build 18363.720.
A solution that requires you to log in, edit the registry, then sign out and sign back in at every startup is appalling. But that's the only solution that worked for me so far.

Comment: @bers How do you restrict permissions to the `Preload` key? Do you have step by step instructions for everything you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I thought my instructions are pretty step by step already. Haven't done that for a year now, though. Which step do you have issues with?

Comment: @bers The "restricting permissions" part. Specifically, which "principals" and what "access" levels, and what "auditing" and/or "effective access".

Comment: @tom_mai78101 I can't tell you much more than what is written above: "converted *all* inherited permissions, removed *all* of them, added read-only permission for `Everyone`". I guess that answers your question regarding principals (again: all).

Comment: @tom_mai78101 "Auditing" is empty for me currently - why do you think auditing is necessary here? Finally, "effective access" is nothing where you can make any changes - you can only see what your changes effect for a specific user or group.

Comment: @bers Thanks, that's all I needed to know.

Comment: Just a note: My computer always gets a German keyboard after I use remote desktop to a computer with English keyboard. So the description in the answer is not 100% correct. But the main problem is the same: I keep receiving a "preload" keyboard and it's annoying.

Answer (score 83):

**Actually, the solution is quite simple and requires no registry editing!**

- Go to to ***Region and Language (previously named Language preferences)***, click on ***English (United States)*** and go to ***Options***.
- If you see "US Keyboard" there, **remove it**, and you're done.
- If the remove button is not working / disabled, add another keyboard first, and then try again.
- *HOWEVER*, if you do not see it there, then click on ***Add a keyboard***, add "US keyboard", then remove that keyboard and you're done.

I figured this out after some trial and error trying out various things, I had the same issue.

Comment: It appears after reboot again.

Comment: The third point is literally: "Have you tried turning it on and off again?"... and that was on point :) Thanks for that!

Comment: Doesn't work after reboot, I tested this before coming up with the solution above

Comment: Yes, doesn't work after restarting or after hybernating the pc.

Comment: After the June 2018 Windows 10 update, the "Remove" setting for English US is disabled. (Grr.)

Comment: This worked for me, and the accepted answer didn't

Comment: F*ing finally! Why the F would Windows add this stupid extra language when it isn't even in the list of keyboards in the first place! Thanks for the "However" step, that's what did it for me.

Comment: This is actually unbelievable. Why does MS consistently force US english on me. Thank you for this quite frankly ridiculous (but correct) fix.

Comment: This works for any primary language and isn't limited to English (Unites States)
In my case Windows is set to German, but I have a custom Unites States International (no dead keys) Layout in my list of input methods for the German language.
With the surplus US English one that makes a total of 3 Keyboard Layouts, but only two ever appear in the list.

Comment: I had to add US English, and Remove it again... 

Comment: I add my report to others' reports: This, unfortunately, does not work after rebooting. Rebooting re-adds the damn keyboard(s) or input languages that the user removed with this default, normal, straightforward method. I've no idea what even starts this circus of automatically added input languages.

Comment: The keyboard gets reinstalled after every reboot

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: It is Windows Settings  > "Language settings" section again in Windows 10

Comment: haven't got rid of additional layouts until I removed and re added the whole language in "Preferred languages" section (no sign out or restart was required)

Comment: The solution presumes you've got US English as a language. In case you don't (yes, those people exist), simply ADD US English language and then nuke it, it'll take the pre-installed US keyboard with it. Works past reboot, at least for me in short testing.

Comment: Last point worked, adding US and removing it again, gone - thank you!

Comment: Combination of this answer and answer from @Ste (copying language settings between Welcome screen, System and New user accounts) worked for me. The language does not show up after reboot.

Comment: The original question wasn't how to remove it, but how to stop it coming back automatically after removing it.

Comment: It's 2023, and it's still a problem. Why would Microsoft do such a stupid thing?

Answer (score 46):

I found the answer after an hour as of now for build:

```
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
OS Version:                10.0.18362 N/A Build 18362
```

1. This will work even after restarting.
2. It's easy to do. And set for good.
3. It will stop any other languages from being created for new users.
4. It will no longer show these languages in the login screen too.
5. No registry hacks which didn't work for me after restarting.

---

You can also go via (***but ensure to check your language settings first - see screenshots below***).

**Control Panel** → **Region** → <kbd>Administrative</kbd> tab → <kbd>Copy settings...</kbd>

---

### Here's the step in images with notation in the images also for reference.

[image: how to]

### Then your registry should look like so, with only one preload.

Copy this `Computer\HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` to the address bar of the registry editor to jump straight to it to check for yourself.

[image: one preload]

Comment: When looking inside **Control Panel** → **Region** → **Administrative tab** → **Copy settings...**, I notice there's a setting where new accounts would always have "English - International" set as the default, while all other settings have "English - US" as the default. I went ahead and copied my settings over to the new account (by ticking the checkbox for new accounts and hit the "Copy Settings" button), so now I'm going to see if this will work.

Comment: This is a proper way to do it, since deleting Preload does nothing - Windows 10 just restores it.

Comment: Bingo! Only that I first needed to explicitly add the language according in @Snaiper answer to be able to then remove it. After I copied the language settings the language got removed from the Preload registry key.

Comment: Hey man, do you know any way to revert this? I have 2 layouts and Windows was adding a 3rd. I did your suggestion but now I can only have 1 ever and I need my 2nd layout. Please tell me you know a way to undo this

Comment: @KrisBonev, I think it is best asked as a new question. Did you try adding a new one as per step 3 in the above screenshot?

Comment: Yeah @Ste ofc, but it just doesn't consider it at all

Comment: I just did this in Windows 11, per instructions in annotated screenshot, and it has solved the problem (for now), will report back if the phantom returns again

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: While the settings screen looks slightly different from the screenshot, this approach is still valid on Windows 11 as well!

Answer (score 18):

This is not the permanent fix, but a handy batch file which adds `en-US` keyboard layout and then removes it (you have to first add it to be able to remove it).

`Remove_en-US.xml`:

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">

    <!--User List-->
    <gs:UserList>
        <gs:User UserID="Current"/>
    </gs:UserList>

    <!--input preferences--> 
    <gs:InputPreferences>
        <!--add en-US keyboard input-->
        <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0409:00000409"/>
        <!--remove en-US keyboard input-->
        <gs:InputLanguageID Action="remove" ID="0409:00000409"/>
    </gs:InputPreferences>

</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

`Remove_en-US.bat`:

```
control intl.cpl,, /f:"%CD%\Remove_en-US.xml"
```

Then you can just run `Remove_en-US.bat` to remove the layout. I set it to run this batch file whenever I unlock my machine in my task scheduler, which finally eliminiated this issue for me.

Here, `0409` is the `locale ID` and `00000409` is the keyboard layout values. For the list of the `locale ID:keyboard layout value` see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-8.1-and-8/hh825682(v=win.10).

Comment: The only solution that works for me on Win 10 1909. Thanks.

Comment: My pleasure! ,By the way, I set this batch file to run whenever I unlock my machine in the task scheduler, which essentially eliminated the issue for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

Theres is two places for keyboard configuration in windows 10, 
control panel -> Language

The other is in setting just like your screenshot

Makes the changes there too, it should fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not it, I have added a screenshot of that screen on my computer, it's correctly configured with "Swiss French" exactly the same way as in the new UI

Answer (score 5):

I didn't have 409 entry in the registry (see accepted anwer). The steps I took to remove English (US) from the quick selection menu:

1. Open "Language Preferences" from the quick selection menu.
2. Add English (US) language.
3. Remove English (US) language.

Tip: In Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Advanced settings -> Change language bar hot keys you can set hot key action for "Between input languages" to "(None)" to avoid accidental keyboard layout switch.

Comment: I think your answer misses the point of this question. The problem is not removing US English language, which I type in and definitely want in my list of languages, the point is to remove a non-existent "US Keyboard" layout that doesn't match my own keyboard layout and that creeps up every once in a while as an additional "language" in the list of languages. There are many threads regarding the removal of US English language itself but this one is not one of them. I also don't mean to remove the language list, I use it to fast switch between languages all the time (for windows' spell checker).

Answer (score 3):

Mikel's answer above fixes this.... but just in case this reappears for you (as it did for me): Do you perhaps have a **custom AutoHotkey shortcut to change keyboard layouts?**

The problem was that my AutoHotkey script contained the following lines of code:

```
; This should be replaced by whatever your native language is. See 
; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
; for the language identifiers list.
el := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000408", "Int", 1)
en := DllCall("LoadKeyboardLayout", "Str", "00000409", "Int", 1
```

So while in my desktop this would work beautifully and switch from English (UK keyboard layout) to Greek (GR keyboard layout) and vice versa, on my laptop that has a US keyboard, this script would be responsible for the extra layouts appearing out of the blue on my language switcher.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 anniversary edition contains a new "feature" where it assumes that both regional and language settings come with a mandatory keyboard layout. Those layouts cannot be removed via the settings GUI.

But I was able to overcome it via PowerShell with a script like this:

```
$1=New-WinUserLanguageList en-US
$1.Add("nl-NL")
$1.Add("de-DE")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $1
```

Copy-paste it into a PowerShell window.

The demo above configures the US layout as a default with the additional NL and BE layouts. Adjust as needed.

Comment: nothing has been changed for me after this command execution

Answer (score 2):

1. Control Panel
2. Clock, Language, and Region
3. Language
4. Change input methods
5. Advanced settings
6. Override for default input method
7. Choose your preferred layout (instead of "Use language list")
8. Save

[image: Screenshot of Input settings -> Advanced settings]

Comment: 'Language' is now missing in the latest win10 updates.

Comment: @platinums Starting in Windows 10 1903/1909, **Languages** has been migrated over to the Windows 10 Settings app.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it seems the issue is also with the same key under your actual user profile (`HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-...\Keyboard Layout\Preload`), not just `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.

I can replicate this pretty consistently - when I add a key 00000429 (Persian) for example there and reboot, I get the Persian keyboard automatically added, and when I delete it and reboot, the Persian is no longer there.

In sum, you may want to make sure that you don't have undesired languages in neither  `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` nor `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-...\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.

Comment: This was the extra step needed to solve my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all the answers above and in a dozen of more places, but unfortunately none of them worked.
However, [Angelos'](https://superuser.com/a/1279805/207117) suggestion above re **Autohotkey** helped me realize that there must be another app that's adding those layouts I removed manually, and it indeed turned out to be true, in my case **LanguageIndicator** was the culprit.

Another clue I've noticed that helped me: @login screen I had only two layouts, and only some time after login the other two useless layouts appeared. After that excluding all auto-login items and then launching them manually allowed to easily find the one app that added those extra layouts.

Answer (score 0):

This one also drives me crazily, specially every time after restart laptop.

Here is one tip I found, hope it also helps each of you:

Firstly, ensuring the new random keyboard is removed, if not found in the keyboard list, please add the keyboard first, then remove it.

Open `Settings`, then in search bar type "typing", Then click "Advanced keyboard settings", then unclick "Let me set a different input method for each app window". Restart to have a test.

[image]

[image]