# How to force Windows 10 to use English with a non English keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

This is how my language settings are currently configured:
[image]

As you can see, the default language should be English and I set the keyboard layout in *Options* to be Swiss-French. That's the only keyboard listed in there.

But randomly, the keyboard will switch to US-EN. Also, some apps are mixing both French and English in the UI, like this:
[image]

I removed the language switching shortcuts so I know it is not that causing the issue. What else can I do to lock the keyboard to CH-FR and have it never change back to US-EN? This is driving me nuts. Also, what can I do about the weird UI?

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1172554/141 might help.