# How to remove additional keyboard layouts if I can't see them in control panel in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, windows-10-v1709

How to remove additional keyboard layouts if I can't see them in control panel in Windows 10?

It currently looks like this (sorry for the UHD):

[image: keyboard layouts the in control panel]

Note: I am new to Windows 10 Pro. I use Linux instead, but I bought it with a very nice laptop.

---

But there are two more layouts and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Any clues would be much appreciated.

---

**EDIT1:** I have just removed Cestina completely but one keyboard layout from that language remained.

---

**EDIT2:** I rebooted, problem solved, the remaining offending language pack disappeared.

Comment: Remove the language pack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to remove keyboard layouts on the Windows 10 1607+.

the first method.

1. Open `Control Panel`
2. Go to `Clock, Language, and Region`
3. Go to `Language`
4. Click on the language pack you want to modify.
5. Click on **Options**
6. Click on keyboard layout you want to remove
7. Click on **Remove**.

[image]

[image]

The second method:

1. Open the UWP Settings application.
2. `Time & language`
3. Go to `Region and language`
4. Click on the language pack you want to modify
5. Click on **Options**
6. Click **Remove** on the keyboard layout you want to remove.

[image]

[image]

You should restart in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need to click on the language pack in that case *Cestina* and a button **Options** will appear. Click on that and you can add and remove the different keyboards specified for that language.

You might simply need to restart your PC. If that doesn't help, have a look at: https://superuser.com/a/1094953/873323