# Windows 10 April 2018 Update added an extra Language and I cannot remove it

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout, input-languages, language-bar, windows-10-v1803

I have just updated to Windows 10 April 2018 Update (1803 / 17134.1)

I had my laptop configured completely as UK with only a UK keyboard layout

Since the update, a US keyboard has been added so I now see the switch icon in my task bar

[image]

It appears that all the keyboard language settings are now migrated to the new Settings app and no longer in the old Control Panel

[image]

However, as can be seen from the screenshot above, the Remove button under the newly added US layout is greyed out (as is the UK one)

How can I remove the US layout?

**UPDATE 1:** I just updated my desktop and it *hasn't* added a US keyboard!

**UPDATE 2:** I added a third language (French) and was able to remove it, the button was enabled. The US remove button remained disabled both after adding French and after removing it.

**UPDATE 3:** I added another English language (Australian) and this cannot be removed! Button is disabled

**UPDATE 4:** I followed this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-remove-us-keyboard-from-windows-10-language-list/1094953#1094953) except I removed the values from the keys for all users and also the values under the Substitutions key. The task bar switch icon is gone but I still have all 3 languages in Settings still

Comment: Have you tried to override it from the `Advanced keyboard settings`? - you can get to it under `Region & language`

Comment: @arieljannai the override is set to UK but that does not enable the remove buttons

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Finally found a solution using PowerShell.

You can view your language list with `Get-WinUserLanguageList`

```
$1 = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US
Set-WinUserLanguageList $1
```

now you can check again your new language list with `Get-WinUserLanguageList`
Logoff, Reboot. After rebooting you can add another languages if needed.

Comment: I used `$1 = New-WinUserLanguageList en-GB` for my UK keyboard, it worked! As usual, Micro$oft are migrating stuff but not doing it properly. Thankfully PS is still there using the same background APIs

Answer (score 17):

Just trying to improve naduvko's answer.

You can directly specify the entire list of languages when running the PowerShell script.

Like this:

```
$1=New-WinUserLanguageList en-US
$1.Add("nl-NL")
$1.Add("de-DE")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $1
```

The first one (en-US in this example) will be the default.

Adjust as needed.

(Yes, it's ridiculous that we need to program PowerShell to modify the fricken input languages)

Comment: This is the ONLY solution that worked for me

Comment: For multiple layouts, you can replace the first three lines with `$1=New-WinUserLanguageList "en-US,nl-NL,de-DE"`

Answer (score -3):

On my Windows (Version 10.0.16299.371) I have a `Set as default` button that seems to be replaced with the arrows in your interface. Try to make the `UK` the default. That would unlock `US` for removal.

Comment: I was looking for that but it's no longer there after the update.

Comment: So what the arrows are there for?

Comment: To set precedence

Comment: 10.0.16299 is the build number of Windows 10 version 1709, which is not even the subject of this question.