# Unable to remove languages from Region & Language on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language

I am unable to remove languages from windows.

I have the following list of 4 languages installed
[image: Settings app image]

I want to keep only English (United States) and Hebrew

The other 2 languages I want to remove but the "Remove" option is disbaled.

Things I tried:
The internet is full of suggestions like:
editing: Computer\HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload
which had no effect

There are suggestions to try using the control panel to edit the languages but the control panel simply links back to the Settings app

There are suggestions to set some language as a default. but the default option simply does not exist

There are suggestion to use the options and remove the keyboard from the installed language. Each language has a single keyboard installed and the option to remove there keyboards is disabled as well.

This is very frustrating and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked:
[Windows 10 April 2018 Update added an extra Language and I cannot remove it](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it)

> Finally found a solution using PowerShell.
>
> You can view your language list with `Get-WinUserLanguageList`
>
> ```
> $1 = New-WinUserLanguageList en-US
> Set-WinUserLanguageList $1
> ```