# Remove Russian language Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language, localization

I had Windows 10 Pro 1803 17134.81 with installed only English language.

A few days ago in updates I got "Пакет локализованого интерфейса на русском" that automatically installed on my PC.

But now I can't remove that
[image]

Default language of interface is English but when I run Lpksetup.exe
[image]

How can I remove Russian language?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the appropriate [Windows 10 version and OS build number](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/)?  If you received the Windows 10 version 1803 update, the following question will probably help you:

Comment: @Run5k Windows 10 Pro 1803 17134.81

Comment: @Run5k Thanks for link. I will remove my duplicated question

Comment: Always glad to help.

Comment: But Lpksetup.exe still show Russian

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Your screenshot indicates that your system language is Russian.  You will have to switch it to English before Windows will allow you to remove it

Comment: I have same problem, but I have two English languages (US and UK)… My system is UK version.

Comment: It helped me: https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it/1319680#1319680

Comment: @VladSpirin yes, it helped me too to hide Russian language but it doesn't uninstall it from my PC.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, but how can I do that? I tried some cases but it doesn't change it