# Reinstall Windows 10 Pro (UK) to another system language (US)?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, language

I have a problem. When I bought my Windows 10 Pro,  I chose English (international), in that time I don't understood that this option is UK version (I need only US version). I added US language, but I have new problem, I can't remove any of English languages. I try to change this problem use PowerShell [I found this solution in superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it/1319680#1319680)

But I still see two languages.

Do I need to reinstall my Windows 10 Pro to another system language?
And if I reinstall my Windows 10 Pro, will my license work?

P.S: sorry for my English, I working on it.

Comment: Have you set it to the other language before trying to remove English (International)?

Comment: Retail or OEM license have fixed language. Volume (corporate ) license gives right to change any time.

Comment: Digital license from Microsoft site (personal) I bought it on Microsoft Store

Comment: I have two languages now + two Slavic languages. If I use  variant from question I delete all languages and see only one US. But when I look at my taskbar I see all languages and I don't know why?! Maybe the best way is reinstall OS, but I worry about license

Comment: As a result, I reinstalled the operating system. Now everything works correctly and the most important - license is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty common question. 
and if i'm right - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31700488/806867) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing worked, then you can try this:

1. Open regedit.
2. Navigate to
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ContentIndex\Language
3. Remove English_UK subkey.