# Windows 10 - Windows Display Languages cause automatic keyboards adding

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I have troubles with Windows 10 keyboard settings. I wish to keep the only two languages and keyboards:

- **English (United States) - US Keyboard**
- **Czech - Czech Keyboard**

However, I see the following settings. The list of preferred languages is complete and there appear only 2 languages - these I want:

[image]

However, upon restarting, the keyboard is somehow set to 4 keyboards, which is annoying and I want to remove both United Kingdom-based keyboards:

[image]

I tried to list all the languages in the PowerShell using the command:

```
Get-WinUserLanguageList
```

Giving me the following output where only the wanted languages appear correclty:

```
LanguageTag     : en-US
Autonym         : English (United States)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United States)
ScriptName      : Latin script
InputMethodTips : {0409:00000409}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False

LanguageTag     : cs
Autonym         : čeština
EnglishName     : Czech
LocalizedName   : Czech
ScriptName      : Latin script
InputMethodTips : {0405:00000405}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

However, upon restarting, the United Kingdom variations of the both English and Czech are somehow imported (sometimes one of them).

I have also tried to remove the content of the following Registry folder with no luck:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload
```

How can I fix this issue? My only goal is to remove all languages and keyboards related to the United Kingdom at all.

My Windows version is:

- Edition: Windows 10
- Version: <s>1803</s> 1903
- Installed on <s>25/07/18</s> 20/09/19
- OS build: <s>17134.885</s> 18362.356

Update 28/09/19: The recent Windows Update didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Look also into registry keys (1) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language` and (2) `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language` and (3) `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile`, to delete the UK keyboard code `00000809`. Check again key `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` to see if it was added again (don't delete the entire key). Create first a System Restore point.

Comment: Thanks for the complete list. I have checked it and yes, `00000809` appeared. I did as u suggested, restarted a laptop and somehow it works as I expect. This might be worth to post as an answer, though. We'll see if the solution is permanent or temporary and I get back to you. :) Thanks.

Comment: Do you know which of the three keys was the one that helped?

Comment: I checked out them all and had to remove only at the (2) registry: `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language`.

Comment: Btw. http://tinyimg.io/i/2HulrGm.png

Comment: Well done. For my part I added an answer.

Comment: I've looked a bit deeper, and indeed it can be syncing from your online account. I have updated my answer to reflect that now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### This is most likely due to [synchronized settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/about-sync-settings-on-windows-10-devices-deebcba2-5bc0-4e63-279a-329926955708).

It could be that [your computer is syncing these settings from elsewhere](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/109397-keyboard-layout-uk-displayed-automatically.html#post1365219). Make sure you turn off the syncing behaviour before you troubleshoot any further:

> >Settings > Accounts > Sync your settings > **Language Preferences (OFF)**

> [image: settings window in windows 10 for syncing through your online profile]

**or:**
There an issue reported about this for 1803, which does not seem to have been resolved. It is a [known issue](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/unable-to-remove-a-language-from-windows-10-april/47c13ea5-79ed-4a29-96d4-47d1264b6838):

**Update**: This should be resolved for version 2004

> If English (United Kingdom) is the current Windows display language, and you then add for instance English (India) to the Preferred languages list, afterwards neither English (United Kingdom) nor English (India) can be removed from the Preferred languages list.

**or:**

> Someone has suggested that **Razer's Synapse software** keeps adding the random layouts. Disabling it on startup fixes all these issues. This could be a problem for some who comes here looking for a solution.

**or:**

> It could also be related to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it) here on superuser.

---

## If you still see the issue, there are a few proposed solutions to this problem:

#### 1 use the old language preferences:

`WIN + R` then type `shell:::{BF782CC9-5A52-4A17-806C-2A894FFEEAC5}` and remove English(United Kingdom) from there.

#### 2 Set en-US as only user language (found [here](https://www.tenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/109340-windows-10-1803-update-added-extra-language-en-us-taskbar.html)):

Open Powershell with Administrative rights and type the following one by one:

```
New-WinUserLanguageList en-US

Set-WinUserLanguageList en-US
```

You will be greeted with:

```
Confirm
Continue with this operation?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Press `Y` to confirm.
**Reboot.**
And install the wanted extra languages again.

#### 3 Yet another way:

1. From the Start menu, search for powershell.
2. Right-click Windows Powershell in the search results and choose Run as administrator.
3. Type or copy/paste the following command at the command prompt, and then press Enter.

> 

```
`Get-WinUserLanguageList`
```

After typing this command, make note of the “LanguageTag” listed for the language you wish to remove, as you will need it in the next step.

4. Type or copy/paste each of the following commands at the command prompt, and then press Enter. In the following commands, instead of typing , replace it with the language tag you wish to remove, such as en-in for English (India).

```
$LangList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$MarkedLang = $LangList | where LanguageTag -eq "<languagecode>"
$LangList.Remove($MarkedLang)

Set-WinUserLanguageList $LangList -Force
```

You can also try [this tutorial](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-force-remove-language-pack-windows-10) from windows central

You can read more about windows language packs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-language-packs-to-windows)

Comment: The 2nd way worked, however, the UK keyboard and surprisingly EN-CS keyboard have been somehow added in few hours of working. Do you know why the version `1903` has the very same issue? I hope Microsoft will do something with it.

Comment: Btw. I'd love to upvote your answer, however, my reputation is insufficient since I paid for the bounty :'D

Comment: I will look into it more deeply. You can of course add my answer as the preferred answer, if it was the preferred one :)

Comment: Have you signed in using a microsoft account, and if so, what languages do you have registered online? If you sign in to your account online and check your settings for languages?

Comment: Yes, it's linked. I took a look to `https://account.microsoft.com/profile/` and at the brief profile info, there is a country set as Display language: čeština (Česko) ~ which means the Czech Republic. I filled this information far in the past because of a place of my current residency. I need is my laptop in the English language and with both English and Czech keyboard.

Comment: Try and set that language to english again (in those settings) and redo the 2 way.

Comment: I had done so and experienced multiple restarts for 2 days and the keyboard layout seems stable. Enjoy the earnt bounty, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

There are two main registry keys where keyboard layouts are found:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language
```

For example, the
[keyboard layout code](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values)
for the United Kingdom keyboard is `00000809`. It will be found under the registry
key in an entry whose value is this string.
Deleting the entry will delete the layout
(leaving the others in place).

Some secondary registry keys where keyboard layouts may be found, which are worth
checking, are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\CTF\SortOrder\Language
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\User Profile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have created a .reg script to put these registries in order so I can use it if the problem happens again. Have my +1 at least :)