# How to remove redundant US keyboard in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

[image]

This is what I have on my language option menu. There are 2 US keyboards of English, but I want to remove one of them. But how can I do that starting from here? I couldn't find any way.
[image]

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1477653/how-to-remove-a-duplicate-keyboard-in-windows-10?rq=1) might be helpful[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1470548/windows-10-windows-display-languages-cause-automatic-keyboards-adding?rq=1)

Comment: Additional related questions here: https://superuser.com/questions/1231049/remove-keyboard-option-from-windows and here: https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10 in case their solutions are useful to you

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1025105/remove-automatically-added-keyboard-inputs-and-prevent-them-from-coming-back-wi?noredirect=1&lq=1) might also help.  It seems all the solutions are the same.  Removed and then add your keyboard layouts;  if your not running 21H1 you should go ahead and perform that upgrade

Comment: @Ramhound yes pure restarting helps!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As a result, after you have done add and remove in your language settings, just restart the computer to kick in the effect.