# Can't remove Windows 10 Keyboard Language

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, input-languages, language-bar

I can't remove a keyboard language and sometimes it changes with no reason, but I can't find any place where it's shown to be removed.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 April 2018 Update added an extra Language and I cannot remove it](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the NO REASON is that you press ALT + SHIFT.

This switches languages and keyboard by design.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258

best regards from Germany