# cant remove extra language from languages bar

Tags: windows

I cant remove the extra languages and language bar I tried every method I found but it did not work.

[image]

<sup>Edit: Language pop-up moved across to save space in image</sup>

Comment: As we don't know "every method you found" you'll need to tell us exactly what you tried so far.

Comment: Which language(s) are you trying to remove?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 April 2018 Update added an extra Language and I cannot remove it](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it)

Comment: I'm trying to remove the Spanish and the Syriac languages

Comment: it did not appear in the preferred languages so how can I remove it