# Delete old Window Display Language after upgrading WIndows 10 Home SL to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, default-settings, regional-settings

I upgraded my account license to Windows 10 Pro from a Windows 10 Home Single Language GB version.
I want to completely remove GB (British English) from my Display Languages but I can not do so.

I changed to US English as the display language and added English with German keyboard layout as an alternative layout because I need to switch between the 2 layouts.
Whenever I use hotkeys to change languages (and keyboard layouts) between US English and German (the two languages I set up in settings) there will always be GB in between. And even after setting US English as my Default Display Language in settings it will STILL show GB as an option in the language toolbar...

Even in an elevated power shell using `Set-WinUserLanguageList` with `-Force` parameter it will achieve nothing.

GB always stays selectable in display languages inside language settings and the languages toolbar...

The "Windows Display Language" dropdown in my settings contains:

English (United States)
English (United Kingdom)
English (Germany)

The "Preferred Languages" section contains:

English (Germany)
English (United States)

I tried adding English (United Kingdom) to preferred languages and deleting it afterwards as well, but it did not remove it from Windows display languages either.

Comment: Does [Remove a Language in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/114093-remove-language-windows-10-a.html) help? Or [Cannot Remove a Language from Windows 10 (Fix)](https://appuals.com/cannot-remove-a-language-from-windows-10/)?

Comment: You might want to start doing backups that are thorough enough to completely restore the system to a previous state before making further changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 April 2018 Update added an extra Language and I cannot remove it](https://superuser.com/questions/1318708/windows-10-april-2018-update-added-an-extra-language-and-i-cannot-remove-it)

Comment: Thank you! Nothing worked except renaming the Install language Registry Key!

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language

Answer (score 1):

I followed one [link](https://appuals.com/cannot-remove-a-language-from-windows-10/) posted by [@Andrew Morton](https://superuser.com/users/272824/andrew-morton) in the comments.

I tried most of the suggested methods even before posting, but the only thing that worked for me out of the new additional ways mentioned there was editing the InstallLanguage registry key.

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language
```

The key value should be the last 4 digits of the [Keyboard identifier](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/windows-language-pack-default-values?view=windows-11).

[Registry Editor InstallLanguage key Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGt6R.png)

After rebooting the en-GB keyboard and display language was finally gone.

Comment: this worked for me on Windows 11 also.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna say that the reaction of @JuToGe solved my issue.

Had it same that in the "Windows Display Language" showing 2 language, by going to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\Language"
And change the both language to 1 entry digit code United States - 0409 now it sees just 1 language.

Remember folks, I had install my Windows 11 language in GB-EN. I also checked with RUN : ''lpksetup'' if there was double listed language and deleted that in that GUI window.

Keep this post alive.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1229564)