# Really fix Win10 to prevent automatically adding keyboard layout

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

Yes, I see that [How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically adding keyboard layouts (i.e. US keyboard)](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke), it is not the fix but just a workaround. That question has been closed for answer so I've to ask a "new" one.
You can fix it if you copy your language preference to default user.
Launch "Windows Settings" (press Ctrl+I) then go to "Time & Language" > "Language" > "Administrative language settings" > "Copy settings" (need the administrative privileges).[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMUgm.gif)

Comment: "That question has been closed" - The question is not closed, it is protected, to prevent low-quality answers from being submitted.  Any user with 10 reputation can actually submit an answer to that question.

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I don't have "10 reputation". Who can transfer my answer to that topic?

Comment: 10 rep is trivial to achieve. Propose 5 edits. Write a proper answer that gets an upvote (on an unprotected question) ...