# How to delete standard Persian keyboard layout on windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

There are two layouts installed for Persian on my laptop.

[image]

I want to uninstall the standard (FAS) layout. But there's only one layout shown in `Region & Language`

[image]

I've also tried to [delete the layout in registry](https://superuser.com/a/1340511/247416). So I navigated to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and deleted the corresponding key but after restarting the system, the key is in the registry

[image]

and `FAS` is shown in keyboard layouts in the lower right corner of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke).  While I believe this might be a duplicate, if I issue the flag, it will be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Within `Time & Language` click on `Language`

[image]

3. Click on Persian and remove the language pack

Comment: @grijeshninama - This answer has numerous formatting problems.  In the future, please verify your formatting of your contributions, before they are submitted.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, it seems its a bug of latest windows update.
I have found no exact solution, but if you add Persian standard and then remove it, it will disappear until next restart.
as my experience after doing this, sometimes it just appear in login page and after login it disappears, but after a while it may come back, usually after a restart (not hibernate).
this helped me for a couple of weeks, but after the latest update of windows it came back and I should to do it again : [How to prevent Windows 10 from automatically adding keyboard layouts (i.e. US keyboard)](https://superuser.com/questions/1092246/how-to-prevent-windows-10-from-automatically-adding-keyboard-layouts-i-e-us-ke)

Comment: Can you be more specific?  There are multiple current versions of Windows 10.  It's not clear which version and build the bug exists on.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to grijesh ninama's answer :

1. type "Language" in the windows search box looking for `language settings`
2. Click on Persian and `remove the language pack`(all keyboards of this language will be deleted)
   (if the problem is that you cannot delete only "**FAS فا**" keyboard not "FA فا" too so go on :)

Afterward, both of your persian keyboards must've been deleted, so you just need to `reinstall "FA فا" keyboard from "Add a language"`.
Now here you are, as if you have been deleted only "**FAS فا**" keyboard.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Language settings and click on Persian then select option.

[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PffPk.png)

In the option page select Persian standard and click on remove.
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exUby.png)