# Why after removal keyboard, it reappears after some time (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, language

I have Windows 10 with UK language. 
But I need to have US and RUS keyboard layouts only, so I have added these

[image: Picture 1]

I've found a method to delete the UK keyboard layout [here](https://superuser.com/questions/685078/how-do-i-remove-english-us-from-windows-8-1)!
I get a result likethis : [image: Picture 2]

But after I reboot my system once or twice the UK keyboard appears again

How do I permanently remove the UK keyboard layout from my system?

Comment: What build of Windows are you using?  [You have changed the regional settings I assume?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HWUQt.png).  I suggest changing the system locale to something other then United Kingdom

Comment: You can also try removing it from `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language`

Comment: An application can add these entries. An application I run always adds English (US) despite the amount of times I remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is a nice feature called "Auto detect Remote Keyboard layout" and this will change you’re layout in the RDP session.

I was able to remove the unwanted layouts by creating an `IgnoreRemoteKeyboardLayout` `DWORD` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` and setting it to 1.

[How do I remove automatically added keyboard layouts?](https://superuser.com/questions/483086/how-do-i-remove-automatically-added-keyboard-layouts)