# How do I remove an input language that appears after restart and doesn't show up in settings?

Tags: windows, windows-10, input-languages, regional-settings

I have 2 keyboards (input languages): English and Russian.

After every update requiring a restart, 2 Latvian input methods show up. So I have in total 4: EN, RU, 2 x LV.

If I go to settings, it only shows 2: EN and RU. So I can't remove LV from here.

**What I tried:**

1. If I manually add LV and remove it, I'm left with 3 layouts: EN, RU, LV. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1fFu.png)
2. The first time it happened, [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/483086/how-do-i-remove-automatically-added-keyboard-layouts) helped. But now the DWORD is set, and keyboards still appear and stay after restarts.
3. Tried changing Country / Display settings / Defualts & Overrides

**The questions:**

- How do I remove the second LV keyboard?
- How do I prevent them from re-appearing?

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro, version 1607. Primary display language: EN.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have installed?  Professional or Home?  What language pack is primary (English or Russian)?

Comment: @Ramhound Professional. Primary language is English.

Comment: Version 1511 or Version 1607.....

Comment: @Ramhound Version 1607. Will add this question text.

Comment: Turns out, it is. See my own answer here. This solved it: http://superuser.com/a/485171/197934

Comment: I believe you can accept it as a duplicate.  *Proper procedure is to flag and close as duplicate, if an existing question exist, with an answer that answers your question instead of creating a duplicate question with a link to that duplicate answer.*

Answer (score 2):

This answer helped: https://superuser.com/a/485171/197934.

1. Delete everything but EN and RU keyboard layouts from `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload`.
2. Restart

This removes keyboards and prevents them from re-appearing.