# How do I permanently disable Windows (system) from creating new values in the registry?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-registry, language, ime

[image]

I'm having to remove/delete these two registry values every time.. (d0010409 and 00000409)

The values you see in the picture are language input English US keyboards that I don't need, since I already have a Korean IME language pack that can toggle back and forth from Korean to English.

But when Windows adds these two values, I can't toggle back and forth with the 'language toggle key'. It completely disables me from doing so.

How do I then permanently disable Windows 11 from creating these?

I've tried changing the registry folder privileges and properties, but to no avail.

Comment: What is the "language toggle key" you use?

Comment: Windows manages the Registry.  There is no need whatever for you to manage it.

Comment: @Yisroel Tech it's a language toggle key called 'hangulmode'. it's a dedicated key only present in korean keyboards.

Comment: Does the answer in https://superuser.com/a/484595/368970 help you?

Comment: omg thanks that actually might work! time will tell tho :/

Comment: Let us know the result

Comment: didn't work unfortunately :/